# How to block User creation in QuickBlox Android API

Tags: android, quickblox

I am making an app with QuickBlox. But I want to manage the users signup through my own server. My plan is to use my existing user base and then my server makes REST calls to quickblox to create corresponding users in its database.
On the App side, I'll provision these users along with their "passwords" over the air for each of my users through my own APIs.
But I see that if anyone modifies my client App (using reverse engineering or by copying the Quickblox auth key/secret from the app), then he can call Users.SignUP API and keep creating any number of users and throw off my scheme.
Is it possible to block user creation from the Android App?

Answer (score 0):

To exclude "signUp" method from QuickBlox Android SDK we recommend to use the following service: http://proguard.sourceforge.net/